# Pi running Web App and GPIO - receiving data through GPIO direct into Web App

Tags: gpio, webiopi

Hi any help would be appreciated I am planning to use the Pi to run(not host) a Web App. I am wondering if the Web app can automatically read data sent into the GPIOs. ie can I automatically pull a JSON file that input data is saved to in an app? Thanks for any help

Comment: We get lots of new users asking can I do A and B. If you get A working then B it becomes a lot easier AND you can then ask a sensible question.

Comment: you appear to be making an assumption that `automatically read data sent into the GPIOs` is synonymous with `automatically pull a JSON file that input data is saved` ... the web app and these two are all different things

Comment: Hy, it's possible by sending HTTP requests to the Web Host server with the data you have read from your GPIO.
For that you need to know how the Web application is designed to POST the right REQUEST.